# Counterexample for $A[[x, y]] = A[[x]][[y]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, topological-rings

Maybe this is an idiot question, but I've heard that $A[[x, y]] = A[[x]][[y]]$ does not hold for $A$ an arbitrary commutative ring with identity, so I would like to know a counterexample, since the obvious homomorphism seems to be an isomorphism because everything converges in the $I$-adic topology, so the structure of the ring seems to be preserved.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** My intention was to ask about the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/23568#23568) saying that $A[[x, y]] = A[[x]][[y]]$ is not true for $\mathbf{topological}$ rings.

Comment: See [this MathOverflow answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/23568/1916)  (and the comments on it).

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks I was trying to find this question.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: This answers the original version of the question, not the modified topological version.

This does hold for any commutative ring.  Perhaps what you're thinking is that when we pass to Laurent series we have

$A((x,y)) \subsetneq A((x))((y))$.

On the right hand side we can have a single element in which all negative powers of $x$ appear, e.g. $\sum_{n \geq 0} x^{-n^2} y^n$.  <s>On the left hand side for any fixed element there must be a least power of both $x$ and $y$.</s>  Curses, foiled again.  Suppose $A$ is a field: then by $A((x,y))$ one usually means the fraction field of $A[[x,y]]$.  This includes all doubly finite-tailed formal Laurent series but also a bit more: e.g.

$\sum_{n \geq 0} x^{-n} y^n = \frac{x}{x-y}$.

This is **very confusing**.  See e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/23568#23568) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103055/notation-for-formal-laurent-series/103081#103081).  In particular the comments to the answer given in the first link assert that the example I gave above of an explicit element of $A((x))(y)) \setminus A((x,y))$ is correct.  I thought there was another MO answer giving the details of that, but I cannot find it at the moment.

Comment: A professor of mine said that $A[[x, y]] = A[[x]][[y]]$ was not always true (though, maybe he meant for rings in general) and a famous mathematician made this mistake, but he could not remember. And I've saw in mathoverflow negation of the assertion for rings (but without a counter example). I'm trying to find it.

Comment: The assertion in mathoverflow say for topological rings, I didn't notice it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for editing, my intention was to ask about the answer of Martin given in the link above.